# localStorage, find the difference within the old and new value

Tags: javascript

I need to find out the difference in the old and new value of the localStorage when the change event if triggered.

I can toggle the same localStorage key within different tabs, so if I add one the values would be:

```
'1234,4321'
```

But then when I remove one it would be:

```
'1234'
```

My code below will convert the string to an array, separating the comma. However this only seems to work on way around, so if I remove one the code below will display an empty array, instead of the removed number.

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'favourites') {

        let newv = e.newValue.split(',').filter(id => !!id);
        let oldv = e.oldValue.split(',').filter(id => !!id);

        let difference = newv.filter(function (i) {
            return oldv.indexOf(i) === -1;
        });

        console.log(difference);
    }
});
```

What is the best way to do this!?

Comment: Why `.filter(id => !!id);` ?? Why are you using filter like that?

Comment: Remove any potential empty splits

Answer (score 0):

So you need to check for added by looking to see if the original does not have it from the new values. And to check for a removed item, you need to check that the id does not exist in the orginal values.

```js
const oldValue = '1234,4321'
const newValue = '1234,5555'

const oldValueIds = oldValue.split(",")
const newValueIds = newValue.split(",")

const removed = oldValueIds.filter(id => !newValueIds.includes(id))
const added = newValueIds.filter(id => !oldValueIds.includes(id))

console.log('removed: ', removed)
console.log('added: ', added)
```